# Use one component within another

Tags: vue.js

I want use one component within another component depending on a condition.

exemple:

if(condition is true){
call component
}

it's possible?

I tryed use v-html but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Use condition rendering.

```
<h1 v-if="awesome">Vue is awesome!</h1>
<h1 v-else>Oh no </h1>
```

[Here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) you can find more details

Answer (score 0):

v-if and import component ? or try v-show

```
<div v-if='conditionIsTrue'> 
  <randomComponent /> 
</div>

<script>
import randomComponent from '@/components/component'

export default{
 components: {
  randomComponent
 }
}
</script>
```